# I want to open a software GUI on ubuntu SERVER.

Tags: user-interface, cassandra, command-line-interface, ubuntu-server

I would like to know open a GUI of a software called datacenter datastax which is a UI for Cassandra where we can manipulate the data.

Firstly, I want to install datacenter on my office server where multiple VMs are setup. Out of one of those VMs, I have created a fresh 'ubuntu server' VM and install the datacenter within. Since ubuntu server is only based on CLI but the data center is all GUI. How come I achieve this? I mean I want to access the GUI of this software while it's installed within a ubuntu server.

Reason for me doing this is because every person within the office can access the GUI of the datacenter when I share them the ip or whatever.

Please help me with this. Ill highly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to export the console from the server to the machine you want to access GUI from.

Something similar like this export DISPLAY=":0.0" where you replace ip_address with the ip address of the machine that you want to send GUI to, if the machine is some *nix machine. Then run the command to start the GUI. After this, the GUI should be redirected to the machine having the

If it is a Windows machine, you will need to run xming on it.

Also, please note that this is not a Cassandra related question, even if you want to start a Cassandra related GUI.